# ADB not seeing device after update

Tags: adb

I just updated the Android SDK Tools to 22.6.4 and the Google USB Driver to Rev. 10 and now ADB cannot see the device.

Device: Honeywell Dolphin 70e Black with 4.0.3

Modified the android_winusb.inf to include:

```
;Honeywell 70e
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C2E&PID_0BA3
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C2E&PID_0BA3&MI_01
```

I was able to install the driver just fine and everything else seems normal except ADB with this device. Other devices work fine (Droid X, Kindle Fire, Motorola Photon Q)

I have done ADB resets, computer restarts, I downloaded an older version of the tools (22.6.2 and Rev 9 driver) but was still unable to connect. I even did a factory reset on the Honeywell device.

I can't think of anything else to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot about the adb_usb.ini file in the `\USER_NAME\.android` folder. Added `0x0C2E` to the bottom, restarted ADB and all is good.

So, full instructions:

Get device hardware Ids from Device Manager in the form of `USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&MI_90`

ENABLE DRIVER:

Open file `\android-sdks\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf`

Add

```
;Device Name
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&MI_90
```

Under both

```
[Google.NTx86]
[Google.NTamd64]
```

Save and close.

INSTALLING DRIVE:

Find device in Device Manager and Update Driver.

- Choose Browse
- Let me pick
- Have Disk
- Browse
- select `\android-sdks\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf`
- OK
- choose `Android Composite ADB Inerface`
- Next
- accept unsigned warning if shown. For Windows 8 you may need to enable the installation of unsigned drivers, just Google it.

UPDATE ADB:

Open file `\USE_NAME\.android\adb_usb.ini`

add to the bottom `0x1234` (this is the VID part with the 0x identifying it as hexadecimal)

Save and close

Restart the ADB by either

Eclipse:

- Show the `Devices` view
- Click the facing down triangle in the top right corner of the view
- Click `reset adb`

Command Prompt:

- Open command prompt
- cd to your `\android-sdks\platform-tools\` folder
- Run `adb kill-server`
- Run `adb start-server`

All Done.